# Padding string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to pad a string in Kotlin to achieve some proper alignment on the console output. Something along these lines:

```
accountsLoopQuery                             - "$.contactPoints.contactPoints[?(@.contactAccount.id)]"
brokerPassword                                - *****
brokerURI                                     - tcp://localhost:61616
brokerUsername                                - admin
contactPointPriorityProperties                - "contactPointPriority.properties"
customerCollection                            - "customer"
customerHistoryCollection                     - "customer_history"
defaultSystemOwner                            - "TUIGROUP"
```

I have ended up coding it this way - cheating with Java's String.format:

```
mutableList.forEach { cp ->
    println(String.format("%-45s - %s", cp.name, cp.value))
}
```

Is there a proper way to do this with the Kotlin libraries?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`.padEnd(length, padChar = ' ')` extension](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-end.html) from `kotlin-stdlib` for that. It accepts the desired `length`  and an optional `padChar` (default is whitespace):

```
mutableList.forEach {
    println("${it.name.padEnd(45)} - ${it.value}")
}
```

There's also [`padStart`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html) that aligns the padding in the other direction.

Comment: good answer. I have tried what you suggested and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You can using [String#format](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html) extension function instead, In fact, it is inlined to call-site function with [java.lang.String#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for example:

```
mutableList.forEach { cp ->
    println("%-45s - %s".format(cp.name, cp.value))
}
```

Comment: @gil.fernandes Not at all. glad it helped you.